# Why do we use spread operator for function in JS?

Tags: javascript

In this code, I don't understand the use of spread operator (...) before calling the function in the if statement. In the code below, the answer is [1, 2, 3, 4] which is the correct answer.

```
    function steamrollArray(arr) {
    const flattenedArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
        flattenedArray.push(...steamrollArray(arr[i]));
      } else {
         flattenedArray.push(arr[i]);
      }
    }
    return flattenedArray;
  };

console.log(steamrollArray([1, [2], [3, [[4]]]]))
// answer = [1, 2, 3, 4 ]
```

However, if I delete the spread operator the function calling, answer will be [ 1, [ 2 ], [ 3, [ [Array] ] ] ]. I don't understand the use of spread operator in this context.

```
    function steamrollArray(arr) {
    const flattenedArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
        flattenedArray.push(steamrollArray(arr[i]));
      } else {
         flattenedArray.push(arr[i]);
      }
    }
    return flattenedArray;
  };

console.log(steamrollArray([1, [2], [3, [[4]]]]))
// answer = [ 1, [ 2 ], [ 3, [ [Array] ] ] ]
```

Comment: `var myarray = [0,1,2]; myarray.push(3,4); console.log(myArray);` vs `var myarray = [0,1,2]; myarray.push([3,4]); console.log(myArray);`

Comment: Clearly the spread syntax is flattening the array, unpacking it into separate arguments instead of pushing the array object itself.

Comment: Try `const arrA = [], arrB = []; arrA.push(1, 2); arrB.push([1, 2]); console.log({ arrA, arrB });`. `.push(...[1, 2])` is equivalent to `.push(1, 2)`.

Comment: Spread operator always creates a NEW INSTANCE of the variable. In your example if you remove the spread, first change of the ORIGINAL array will break the logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spread syntax *(it's not an operator)* **spreads out** the entries from the array into discrete arguments to `push`. So for instance, if `steamrollArray` returnd `[1, 2, 3]`, then

```
flattenedArray.push(...steamrollArray(/*...*/));
```

would be like

```
flattenedArray.push(1, 2, 3);
```

That calls `push` with three separate arguments (the elements from the array). But if you remove the spread, it's like:

```
flattenedArray.push([1, 2, 3]);
```

That calls `push` with **one** argument: an array to push. So you end up with an array inside the array, instead of the array's *elements* in the array.

Compare:

```js
const someArray = [1, 2, 3];

const flattenedArray = [];
flattenedArray.push(...someArray);
console.log(flattenedArray);
```

with

```js
const someArray = [1, 2, 3];

const flattenedArray = [];
flattenedArray.push(someArray); // no spread
console.log(flattenedArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

The "three dots" or the spread syntax turns an array into a list of individual values, like arguments in a function call:

```
(...[1,3,3])   -->    (1,2,3)
(   [1,2,3])   -->    ([1,2,3])
```

In the context of the `steamroller()` this is the chosen way to flatten each individual array element.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should know that the `push` method accept any number of argument.
ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Secondly, the spread operator will help you `flat` the array become each argument of method.
For example,

```
const b = [1,2,3,4];
x.push(...b) // 
x.push(1,2,3,4)//
```

Here is your function without spread operator

```
function steamrollArray(arr) {
  const flattenedArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
      const result = steamrollArray(arr[i]);
      for (let j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
        flattenedArray.push(result[j]);  
      }
      
    } else {
      flattenedArray.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return flattenedArray;
};
```